# DotNetZip wrong password while unzipping

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, zip, dotnetzip

Scenario: upload file than try zip it using `DotNetZip` with password protection, password is generated with `Membership.GeneratePassword()` method. Everything is working fine except that sometimes user is not able to unzip files with generated password. Wired thing is that this happens only sometimes let's say 1 out of 15 times.
Generate password:

```
public static String FilePassword()
{
    while (_filePassword.Length < 12)
    {
        _filePassword += string.Concat(Membership.GeneratePassword(1, 0).Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
    }

    return _filePassword;
}
```

Save file:

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{

    fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(FileSavePath + fileName);

        // Archive uploaded file to zip.
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            // File to be archived.
            var file = FileUploadControl.PostedFile;

            // Enable encryption of file
            zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;

            // Set password.
            zip.Password = Settings.FilePassword();

            // Set temporary folder path for archive process.
            zip.TempFileFolder = tempPath;

            // Add file to archive with its path.
            zip.AddFile(FileSavePath + file.FileName, "");

            File objFile = new File(file.FileName, FileSavePath); 

            // Save zip file with the name as file ID.
            zip.Save(FileSavePath + file.FileName);
        }
}
```

I logged password while creating in method and also while protecting zip file with password, they are always matching, I cannot see what's wrong, why sometimes while unzipping file it shows wrong password.

Comment: Can you show us some examples of passwords that did work and didn't work?

Comment: Did you checked the character encodings of the passwords?

Comment: @mjwills password is alphanumeric, one of working pass: vKkowRZBtIxo, not working one: QjCFFaM9LumZ

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use the static global variable `_filePassword` in `FilePassword()` instead of one in scope?

This way it could be modified from outside, or possible even still contain the last used value. Also it isn't thread safe without `lock`.

Settle with a local variable and it should be fine.

```
public static String FilePassword()
{
    string retString = string.Empty;
    while (retString.Length < 12)
    {
        retString += string.Concat(Membership.GeneratePassword(1, 0).Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit));
    }    
    return retString;
}
```

You can log a return Value too.

---

**Sample for understanding**

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{

    fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(FileSavePath + fileName);
    string filePassword = Settings.FilePassword(); // Contains the Password

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        var file = FileUploadControl.PostedFile;
        zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.PkzipWeak;            
        zip.Password = filePassword; // <-- Set password for ZIP
        zip.TempFileFolder = tempPath;
        zip.AddFile(FileSavePath + file.FileName, "");
        File objFile = new File(file.FileName, FileSavePath);
        zip.Save(FileSavePath + file.FileName);
    }

    // Log this value!
    Log(filePassword);
}
```

Comment: good point. It was from previous code when password was generated directly with `GeneratePassword` method so it was also with special characters. Will give your suggestion a try to see if it helps.

Comment: @Mony You could try if your issue happens, if two users simultaneous requesting a Zip File.

Comment: your change generates 4 different passwords and non of them is correct for unzipping file. my log: `10/4/2017 11:22:55 AM => Password from FilePassword method: iowSYgGB4Nbi
10/4/2017 11:22:55 AM => Password from FilePassword method: mmnZeM1sz3ln
10/4/2017 11:22:55 AM => Password from zipping file: mmnZeM1sz3ln
10/4/2017 11:22:57 AM => Password from FilePassword method: 3xUeKXkWveIv
10/4/2017 11:22:58 AM => Password from FilePassword method: nKNZW67O6yi1` notice the zipping file password which was used while zipping, even this one is not working

Comment: @Mony Did you use the same variable for Zipping and Logging?

Comment: yes I did, only way how to have same value all the time is my original way of generating password. Because password is used on multiple places not only while zipping.

Comment: @Mony The use of a static is almost certainly the cause of your issues. You need to use a local variable and pass it around rather than use a static. Or use `HttpContext.Items` http://odetocode.com/Articles/111.aspx